# Development env NodeJS and Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

I created the following Dockerfile

```
ROM node:argon

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Everything works fine when I build and run the Docker image

However, when I run

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -v ~/projects/NodeJSExample/:/usr/src/app/ nodeexample
```

I got :

```
Error: Cannot find module 'express'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/server.js:3:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
```

How can I configure Dockerfile to support code changes dynamically?

Comment: Had you run an `npm install` locally before mounting the directory?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're facing is that you declare a volume on your container's `/usr/src/app/` folder. What it does is that it replaces your container's folder by the one on your filesystem, which certainly did not have the `npm install` command executed.

As if, your Dockerfile is valid, and you can distribute it like that. But for local development purpose, you can't have the `npm install` be run on the image (Dockerfile) itself. So you only need to run the `npm install` command on your local `~/projects/NodeJSExample/` while your container is up, and you're good to go.

Comment: Running `docker run --rm -it -v ~/projects/NodeJSExample/:/usr/src/app/ nodeexample npm install` might grab the deps to the volume.

Comment: Agreeed, but then add the "--rm" option to delete the container after that, as  it won't be useful anymore

Comment: Yup, edited the command. And also added `-it` if there might be any interactions needed.